# why is thlis list phenomenon in python?

Tags: python, list

```
n = int(input())
chess =[[]]*n

for i in range(n) :
    for j in range(n):
        chess[i].append(0)

print(chess)
```

I want to make list as N x N. but this cord make list as N x (N^2). why is thlis list phenomenon?

Comment: Because `chess =[[]]*n` creates a list with *n references to the same list*. So *any* time you `chess[i].append(0)` you are appending *to the same list*

Comment: You can just use `[[0 for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(n)]`